# Translation of a sentence < 私はどれ程の人間...>

Tags: translation, meaning, words

I can't understand this どれ程{ほど}の人間{にんげん} part well:

> その人{ひと}の中{なか}で、私{わたし}は**どれ程の人間**になっているというのか。

Is it something like:

> What kind of person do they think I am?

Answer (score 4):

どれ程の人間 in this sentence means どれ程重要な人間. The sentence means "I wonder how important I am to the person."

Comment: I'm sorry. How did you guess if person has become how **important** he/she is?

Comment: Ugh got 2 downvotes. So here, 立派な ( respectful ) is not a choice.

Comment: Or something like, "how much I grew up"?

Comment: I think he has a point there.  What exactly "どれ程の人間" ("how much of a human/person (someone is)") means is not as unequivocal as this answer may be taken to suggest. It generally asks how "great" someone is as a person, but great in what respect it is specific to each instance. It can be with reference to the person's character, worth, importance, stature, (moral) respectability, etc. We could definitely use a bit of context, in order to explore the meaning of this and other parts of the sentence.